# Find the number of functions such that $f (f (f (n))) =n$

Tags: combinatorics, functions

[image]

What is the idea of this problem?

Comment: @Arnaldo I need hint to go

Comment: try a combinatorial approach. Look the possibilities.

Comment: If you know group theory, then the question is asking for the elements of order $1$ or $3$ in $S_6$. Apart from the identity, you only have to consider products of $3$-cycles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for elements of $S_6$ whose order divides 3. There are three types of such elements:

1. The identity. There is only 1.
2. Three cycles. There are $\binom{6}{3}*2$ of these.
3. The product of two disjoint three cycles. There are $\binom{6}{3}*2 $ of these.

Hence the answer should be $\binom{6}{3}*2 + \binom{6}{3}*2 + 1 = 20*2 + 20*2 + 1 = 81$.

Comment: There aren't that many products of two disjoint three cycles, you've counted each one twice. You've counted choosing for example (123) and then (456) seperately to choosing (456) and then (123).

Comment: @PJF49 The second 2 represents (465) vs (456) (the first two was (123) vs (132))

Comment: @PJF49  what is the right  number ?

Comment: I understand that. Think of it another way, you have $\binom{5}{2}$ choices for what you put in the same three cycle as 1 and then you multiply that by 4 due to the different three cycles with the same numbers so there are $\binom{5}{2}*4 = 40$ double three cycles.

Comment: @PJF49 Ah, yes. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

If the function is an identity when iterated three times, its graph is made of cycles of length $1$ (i.e. $f(n)=n$) or $3$ only.

Study the possible graphs. One can decompose as $6\times1,3\times1+1\times3$ or $2\times3.$

Comment: what is meant by a cycle of length  $3$

Comment: @prayersmith: hem, please make an effort.

Comment: @   Yves Daoust I didn't  study  group theory yes